# Blocked by apache after backup

Tags: apache

I did a backup of several files from my remote VPS Ubuntu/LAMP set up to my desktop. Now my IP address has been blocked. The apache error log tells me my IP address is "client denied by server configuration".

I've no idea why this happened. All I did was SFTP a few backups from Filezilla, then deleted the remote backups, and checked a few logged messages. It was working fine until around the time the backup finished.

Please advise, thanks

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing the relevant parts of your http servers host configuration? We cannot look over your shoulder, not can we _guess_ that.

Comment: Also on the same line in the error log it says "[evasive20:error]"

Comment: No idea what that is meant to say, it does not look like an entry in an apache http server error log file.

Comment: Sorry, here the output from apach2 error.log file .... [Mon Jun 06 05:36:49.508620 2016] [evasive20:error] [pid 2211:tid 140643041003264] [client ***my ip address***:56679] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/

Comment: This type of entry only shows if I refresh my webpage a few times then the error changes from a 404 to a 403.

Comment: And the relevant part of the host configuration?